# set timeout for script and show pop when its due

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to set a timeout for this script and also show a popup when the timeout is due

```
$scope.mainloginAlert = function() {
                var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Error',
                template: '<p align="center">Incorrect Username or Password</p>',
                });
                };

    $scope.mainlogin= function(){
    $ionicLoading.show({template: '<p>Please Wait...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'});
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://web.usersite.com/scripts/login.php",
        {'username':$scope.username,'pwd':$scope.pwd})
        .success(function(data){
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));;

            {$ionicLoading.hide();}

            if(data==="Incorrect Username or Password"){
            $scope.mainloginAlert()
    }
                else{
                if(data != "Incorrect Username or Password"){
                localStorage.setItem("username",(data[0].username));
                $window.location.href = 'userpage.html';
                    }
                }

                }).error(function(error){
                    console.error(error);
                    });
                }
}])
```

Cos without a timeout for the loader to stop spinning. it will keep on spinning even if there's no internet connection

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use angular's wrapper for this:

```
$scope.mainlogin= function(){
  $timeout(hideLoader, 5000)
  function hideLoader() {
    $ionicLoader.hide()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

js code: this loading or popup will be shown till 2.5 seconds, that's the hint, replace with your credentials. I hope it works

```
$scope.post = function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Posting ...'
    });
    console.log('Posting ', $scope.load);
    $timeout(function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.closePost();
    }, 340);
};
```